# Wheres my error? Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple script, not sure where the error is coming from. Think I have my blinders on!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var listingId = "<!-- TMPL_VAR listing_id -->";
    var photoCount = "<!-- TMPL_VAR photo_count -->";
    var photoNum = 1;
    for(i=photoNum; i<=photoCount; i++) {
        $('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="active item"><img src="/property/photo/' + listingId + '/' + i'" /><div class="carousel-caption"><!-- TMPL_VAR remarks_general --></div></div>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Missing a `+` but also declare the counter as a var: `for(var i=1; i<=photoCount; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `+` in this line

```
$('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="active item"><img src="/property/photo/' + listingId + '/' + i'" /><div class="carousel-caption"><!-- TMPL_VAR remarks_general --></div></div>');
```

Try like this

```
$('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="active item"><img src="/property/photo/' + listingId + '/' + i+'" /><div class="carousel-caption"><!-- TMPL_VAR remarks_general --></div></div>');
```

Answer (score -1):

At first I can see you are missing `+` at img tag for src attribute. Added `+` after `i`

```
var listingId = " TMPL_VAR listing_id";
    var photoCount = "<!-TMPL_VAR photo_count";
    var photoNum = 1;
    for(var i=photoNum; i<=photoCount; i++) {
        $('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="active item"><img src="/property/photo/' + listingId + '/' + i+'" /><div class="carousel-caption"><!-- TMPL_VAR remarks_general --></div></div>');
    }
```